# Merge sort in declarative style with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, mergesort

ES6 syntax helps to write code in a declarative style, which is exactly what I am trying to achieve here. Any advice to make my code "more declarative" (and easier to read) is welcomed.

```
const middleIndex = xs => Math.floor(xs.length / 2);

const split = xs => {
    return {
        fst: xs.slice(0, middleIndex(xs)),
        snd: xs.slice(middleIndex(xs))
    };
};

const isSingleton = xs => xs.length === 1;

const any = xs => xs.length > 0;

const dropHead = xs => xs.shift();

const head = xs => xs[0];

// Arrow functions cannot be generators. Damn it!
const merge = function* (xs, ys) {
    while (any(xs) && any(ys)) {
        yield dropHead(head(xs) < head(ys) ? xs : ys);
    }

    while (any(xs)) {
        yield dropHead(xs);
    }

    while (any(ys)) {
        yield dropHead(ys);
    }
}

const sort = xs => {
    if (isSingleton(xs) || !any(xs)) {
        return xs;
    }

    const { fst, snd } = split(xs);

    return [...merge(sort(fst), sort(snd))];
}
```

Comment: I should have made some `head` function instead of use `xs[0]`...

Comment: As long as nobody has posted any answer yet, you can still tweak the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd move the helper functions into `sort`'s scope. Names like `any` and `merge` are very generic, and don't need to be cluttering up the global scope.

I also question the need for some of the functions, especially `dropHead`. It's just a synonym for `Array.shift`, so why not just call `shift`? All you get is a function with side-effects; since `shift` modifies the receiver, `dropHead` modifies the passed-in array, but at an extra level of, well, obfuscation almost.

The naming of `isSingleton` isn't great either. "Singleton" in OO languages usually has precise meaning. In mathematics it refers to a single-element set, but in a programming context I'd expect it to check whether the array object itself is a singleton.

In the end, I'd just say `array.length === 1` where needed. And `any` can be replaced with `array.length > 0` or even `array.length` as zero is falsey. Is it as declarative? Maybe not, but in my opinion it's more readable JS than inventing new expressions.

Conversely, I see no reason to skimp on the naming of variables and properties. Why `fst` and `snd` instead of simply `first` and `second`? Why `xs` instead of just `array` or `items` or `list`? If the goal is to be declarative, I see little point to use overly terse naming.

Your main `sort` function has a subtle gotcha: If you return early because the array is a "singleton" or empty, you return the same array reference that was passed in. If there's actual sorting going on, you return a *new* array object. So the function essentially has two distinct behaviors depending on input - dangerous. I'd recommend that the early return uses `xs.slice(0)` (or just `xs.slice()`) to ensure that it's *always* a copy that's returned.

There are a few ES6 features you can use, although support is spotty. One is to use array destructuring instead of object destructuring to assign the return value(s) from `split`. It obviates the need for `fst`/`snd`, and by returning an array you ensure ordering, rather than having to explicitly assign `fst` and `snd` in order, or even having to know those property names. E.g.

```
const [head, tail] = split(array); // where split() returns a 2-element array
```

Returning an array also means you can simply run it through `map` instead: `split(array).map(sort)`.

Also, you don't need the two extra `while` loops to yield the elements of `xs` and `ys` in your `merge` function; you can simply delegate the yielding to the arrays themselves:

```
yield* xs;
yield* ys;
```

In all, I'd write something like:

```
const sort = array => {
  const split = array => {
    const middle = array.length >> 1; // should be a safe use of bitwise trickery
    return [array.slice(0, middle), array.slice(middle)]
  };

  const merge = function* (a, b) {
    while(a.length && b.length) {
      yield a[0] <= b[0] ? a.shift() : b.shift();
    }

    yield* a;
    yield* b;
  }

  if(array.length < 2) {
    return array.slice(0); // always return a copy
  }

  return [...merge(...split(array).map(sort))];
}
```

I've skipped the `head` function as it'd only be used twice - in the same line even. The remaining helper functions are nicely "symmetrical": Split and merge.

---

Edit: Just realized something: Your sorting isn't stable. In fact, it's precisely *not* stable. A quick test:

```
 var test = [1, "1", 2, "2", "3", 3]; // already sorted

 test = sort(test) // =>  ["1", 1, "2", 2, 3, "3"]
 test = sort(test) // =>  [1, "1", 2, "2", "3", 3]
 test = sort(test) // =>  ["1", 1, "2", 2, 3, "3"]
 // ...
```

Long story short: The `merge` branching should use `<=` rather than `<` when deciding which array to shift from. I've corrected the code in this answer.

---

Addendum: It might be more declarative and pattern-matching'y to use a `switch` statement to determine whether to return early:

```
const sort = array => {
  const split = array => {
    const middle = array.length >> 1;
    return [array.slice(0, middle), array.slice(middle)]
  };

  const merge = function* (a, b) {
    while(a.length && b.length) {
      yield a[0] <= b[0] ? a.shift() : b.shift();
    }

    yield* a;
    yield* b;
  }

  switch (array.length) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
      return array.slice();
    default:
      return [...merge(...split(array).map(sort))];
  }
}
```

Comment: I was just thinking about the problem with `dropHead`, you are completely right. Using `yield* a` is actually a nice trick that I didn't know. The names I used (`xs`, `singleton` etc) are very expressive for someone from a FP lang IMHO ([see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.singleton%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) and [see section 4.1](https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_read_Haskell)). I moved from `thing.verb()` to `verb(thing)` cause it seems more declarative to me, just a matter of style. Thank you for your review, it is really valuable.

Comment: @Gabriel True, `verb(thing)` is more traditionally functional; as you say it's a matter of style. But given that JS is OO, it makes for slightly strange mix, especially with something like `shift` that both modifies the receiver and returns a value. Speaking of OO, I updated my answer slightly to use `map` for the sub-sorting. Not necessarily nicer, just something that occurred to me. Oh, and the `xs`/`ys` names: Have seen them before, now you mention it, just rarely in JS. They're tough to name regardless; I just used `a` and `b`, which doesn't do much either.

Comment: @Gabriel Should add: I didn't know about the `yield*` delegation either, but it seemed like something that'd exist given that arrays implement the iterator protocol. Happy to learn that my hunch was correct :)

Comment: @Gabriel Just noticed that your sort function isn't stable, but it's easily fixed. Added a note about it to my answer (also fixed a missing `...`)

Comment: Good note about `switch` statement, it really feels like pattern matching. And very good catch about non-stable sorting (I didn't even think about it while coding this one! :-P).

Comment: An advice to others: Although this review is marked as accepted, other reviews will be appreciated too.